# Nextjs router loading takes minutes

Tags: next.js

Good day, I have a simple nextjs app and it suddenly takes forever to load a single page. I inspected it and it seems that the router fetch is taking a long time (2 mins).. Not sure why.

First entry shows that the loading time is 2 minutes.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QwwK.png)

Seems to only affect localhost? I have it on Vercel (live) and this does not happen.

Comment: You need to provide more info, some code. Or if you have getInitialProps, serverSide, staticProps. something

Comment: @GandalfTheGray Thanks for your reply. I've solved it. It's not slow when deployed on Vercel. Also I made a mistake in returning all 300,000 documents under getStaticPaths, which should only be returning a smaller number of paths required at build time, as recommended by Vercel - https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: What was the main problem?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it. It's not slow when deployed on Vercel. Also I made a mistake in returning all 300,000 documents under getStaticPaths, which should only be returning a smaller number of paths required at build time, as recommended by Vercel - https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration